# bash associative array key string with colon is giving error

Tags: bash, unix, associative-array

I am creating an associative array of source and destination MAC addresses.

```
$ declare -a SrcDstMap
$ SrcDstMap["9c:4e:20:73:e2:72"]="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
-bash: 9c: value too great for base (error token is "9c")
$ SrcDstMap["fc:4e:20:73:e2:72"]="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
-bash: fc:4e:20:73:e2:72: syntax error in expression (error token is ":4e:20:73:e2:72")
```

How can I tell bash that the given key is a whole string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not an associative array. You need to use `declare -A`, not `declare -a`.

```
$ declare -A SrcDstMap
$ SrcDstMap["9c:4e:20:73:e2:72"]="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
$ declare -p SrcDstMap
declare -A SrcDstMap=([9c:4e:20:73:e2:72]="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" )
```

---

`declare -a` creates a numerically indexed array, so the shell is trying to parse your index as a number.

Comment: i am on osx; macOS says no option -A

Comment: @neckTwi, Apple refuses to be bound by the GPLv3, and so ships bash 3.2 -- an ancient release that doesn't have associative arrays at all. Use MacPorts to install bash; that'll give you something modern.

Comment: how to install it with home-brew?

Comment: Homebrew is poorly designed from a security perspective (requiring system security to be weakened in a manner that allows any program running as the user who installed it to put new software in the PATH). As a matter of practice, I don't encourage its use, and thus will not provide assistance in using it.

Comment: Can I have MacPorts along with homebrew? I am afraid of messing the things

Comment: ...that said, assuming that you *do* use homebrew, macports, or something else to install a newer non-default shell before the system-provided one in your PATH, use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the shebang for your scripts, and they'll honor the PATH in selecting a shell to run with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127306/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-necktwi).

Comment: Here is how to use latest BASH with home brew: `brew install bash`; add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells`; run `chsh` to change default shell.